# How to remove \r\n character in regex python

Tags: python, regex

```
formatter_fn = lambda sentence: re.sub(r'([^\s\w\.])+', '', sentence).lower()
formatter_fn('\r\ndirected; by Nolan.')
```

This gives the output as `\r\ndirected by nolan.` but I want it as `directed by nolan.`

How to remove `\r\n` in this case ?

Thanks!

Comment: Would `...lower().lstrip('\r\n')` be suitable? Or could the `\r\n` occur anywhere in the string?

Comment: IT could occur anywhere in the string

Comment: Maybe add an `|(\r\n)`?

Comment: It works if I remove \s and then add an empty white space.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
re.sub(r'[^ \w\.]', '', sentence).lower()
```

`\s` is equivalent to the set `[ \t\n\r\f]` but you require only blank space (I guess).

So when you use

```
re.sub(r'[^\s\w\.]', '', sentence).lower()
```

It will be match anything except ( `space`, `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, `\f` ) <-- part of `\s`, `\w`, and `.`. So it was unable to match `\r` and `\n` in your string.

If you want to include `\t` in your set, then you can use

```
re.sub(r'[^ \\t\w\.]', '', sentence).lower()
```

Comment: I am using this, it works. but I am curous on why 
`re.sub(r'[^\s\w\.]', '', sentence).lower()` is not working. Do you know ?

Comment: @dumper added an explanation in answer

Comment: @dumper If there is more explanation needed, feel free to ask and dont forget to accept it if it helped